# Bind multiple datatable into DataSet.xsd

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, reporting-services

I'm working with Reportviewer tool and I'm using for loop in my Stored procedure and it returns multiple tables, How can i bind these multiples table columns into my dataset.xsd page? Can anyone please help..

`cmd.CommandText = SP_Name;`
`cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;`
`cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ddo_code", ddlDDOCode.SelectedValue);`
`cmd.Connection = con;`
`con.Open();`
`SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);`  ![The table fields which are returns from SP is not showing][1]
`DataSet ds = new DataSet();`
`da.Fill(ds);`
`int Count = ds.Tables.Count;`
`for (int i = 0; i < Count; i++)`
`{`
`DataTable dt = new DataTable();`
`dt = ds.Tables[i];`
`RV_SalDetails.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = "ReportView.Report_Sal_Det.rdlc";`
`RV_SalDetails.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportDataSource("DataSet_Sal",dt));`
`}`

Comment: Need a lot more information, for use to correctly answer

Comment: I'm Working on report process.. If my **SP** returns single table then i can bind it on DataSet.xsd page, and then i'll bind it on my reportviewer control, So i can view the output on my asp page. Now My **SP** returns multiples datatables. But i can't assign the datatables into my DataSet.xsd page. So my report viewer control display nothing, and it shows **A data source instance has not been supplied for the data source 'DataSet_sal'**. Please help..

Comment: what report viewer are you using? is there an application your using? if so what language IDE?  your multipule tables i take it, are to display mulipule values in the report, i.e total sales by country,  total sales by customers who are male.  If so depending on which report viewer your using depends on how to do it.  Example some require simple datasource connections, and you bind them to each control on the report etc.  Some i believe also require sub reports on the report in order to allow mulipule datasources

Comment: I'm trying to display the report using Asp.net **ReportViewer** control using c# coding..

Comment: ok, have you got any sample code of what you trying to do? if so edit your post and we can take a look at what you have so far

Comment: edit your main post with that not here in the comments :)